# JSON.NET some fields are null after deserialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Hello guys I'm having some problems to understand why this is happening

I have this class which I'm trying to deserialize:

```
public class TextConceptValidationJob : ConceptValidationJob<ConceptTextItem, BooleanTermAnswer> 
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public TextConceptValidationJob(string id, TaskType taskType, ConceptTextItem wordItem, IList<BooleanTermAnswer> answerContainers) : this (id, taskType, wordItem, answerContainers, new List<string>())
    {
        Debug.Log (id);
        Debug.Log (taskType);
        Debug.Log (wordItem);
        Debug.Log (answerContainers[0].Term);
    }

    public TextConceptValidationJob(string id, TaskType taskType, ConceptTextItem  wordItem, IList<BooleanTermAnswer> answerContainers, IList<string> goldAnswers) : base (id, taskType, wordItem, answerContainers, goldAnswers)
    {
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return item.Text;
        }
    }

    public string Target
    {
        get
        {
            return item.Target;
        }
    }

    protected override string GetAnnotationString<U> (AnswerContainer<U> answerContainer)
    {
        return answerContainer.Query;
    }

    public override string ToString ()
    {
        return base.JobId + "\t" + Target;
    }
}
```

the Debug.Log prints:

Null

correct enum objects

Null

correct list with correct objects

All the objects are in the abstract superclass of TextConceptValidationJob, which looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class Job <I, T, K> where I : Item where T : AnswerContainer<K>
{

    private string jobId;
    private readonly TaskType taskType;
    protected IList<T> answerContainers;
    protected I item;

    public Job (string jobId, TaskType taskType, I item) : this (jobId, taskType, item, new List<string>())
    {
    }

    public Job (string jobId, TaskType taskType, I item, IList<string> goldAnswers)  
    {
        this.jobId = jobId;
        this.taskType = taskType;
        this.task = GetTaskFromType (taskType);
        this.item = item;
        this.goldAnswers = goldAnswers;
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "jobId")]
    public string JobId
    {
        get
        {
            return jobId;
        }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "item")]
    public I Item
    {
        get
        {
            return item;
        }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "answerContainers")]
    public IList<T> AnswerContainers
    {
        get
        {
            return answerContainers;
        }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "task")]
    public TaskType TaskType
    {
        get
        {
            return taskType;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the example json I can't deserialize:

```
{  
   "jobId":"DISAMBIGUATION#2460",
   "item":{  
      "target":"waste",
      "text":"A piece of land where waste materials are dumped",
      "id":"DISAMBIGUATION#2460#44"
   },
   "answerContainers":[  
      {  
         "term":"agriculture (Farming)",
         "id":"DISAMBIGUATION#2460#44",
         "isSent":false,
         "query":"agriculture (Farming)",
         "lang":"EN"
      },
      {  
         "term":"agriculture (Farming)",
         "id":"DISAMBIGUATION#2460#44",
         "isSent":false,
         "query":"agriculture (Farming)",
         "lang":"EN"
      },
      {  
         "term":"agriculture (Farming)",
         "id":"DISAMBIGUATION#2460#44",
         "isSent":false,
         "query":"agriculture (Farming)",
         "lang":"EN"
      },
      {  
         "term":"agriculture (Farming)",
         "id":"DISAMBIGUATION#2460#44",
         "isSent":false,
         "query":"agriculture (Farming)",
         "lang":"EN"
      },
      {  
         "term":"agriculture (Farming)",
         "id":"DISAMBIGUATION#2460#44",
         "isSent":false,
         "query":"agriculture (Farming)",
         "lang":"EN"
      }
   ],
   "task":"DISAMBIGUATION"
```

For the serialization and deserialization I'm using JSON.NET:

```
    TextConceptValidationJob o = new TextConceptValidationJob("DISAMBIGUATION#2460", TaskType.DISAMBIGUATION, item, list);
    string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (o);
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TextConceptValidationJob> (serialized);
```

Do you have any idea what it could be? Maybe it's something stupid I'm missing but I can't seem to find the problem

Thank you very much

Comment: I can't post 20k lines of code for such a easy to fix problem. I didn't know input in the constructor should match with the json parameters and this was visible in the code I posted. The classes I didn't post don't help at all and lead to other classes. You could have just read my problem more carefully and help me or you could have just moved away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* the problem is in the name of the parameters: Json.NET requires the name of the constructor parameters match the name of the properties.
In your example, at least the portion you posted, you have an "id" parameter on the TextConceptValidationJob, but the parameter (and property) is called jobId on the Job superclass.

Solution: rename the parameters in the constructor called by Json.NET to match the actual name of the properties as defined by the Job superclass.

Good luck!

Edit: the provided solution requires you change the signature of the Json.
If you can't, you could implement in your derived class two properties, id and wordItem, that should just replicate the values on the base jobId and item properties.

```
public string id
{
    get { return jobId; }
    set { jobId = value; }
}
public string ConceptTextItem
{
    get { return item; }
    set { item = value; }
}
```